# Central Limit Theorem on a function of iid Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

> Let $X_1$,$X_2$,...,$X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with common density $$f(x)=\frac{\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}, $$ for $\alpha >0$ and $x>1$.  Define $S_n=[\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i]^{1/n}$.
>
> (a) Use the CDF technique to show that $\ln(X_i)$ follows an exponential distribution and give the mean and variance.
>
> (b) Show that $E(\ln(S_n))=E(\ln(X_1))=\frac{1}{\alpha}$.
>
> (c) Use the Central Limit Theorem to find, as $n \to \infty$, the limiting distribution of $$\sqrt{n}[\ln(S_n)-\alpha^{-1}].$$
>
> (d) Suppose that $\alpha=10$ and $n=100$.  Find $P(S_n>1.12)$.  Give the result as a function of the cumulative c.d.f. of the standard normal distribution $\phi(\circ)$.

I've done (a) and (b) but am stuck on (c) and consequently cannot do (d).  I know I can put the $\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator as $1/\sqrt{n}$ but from there I'm stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably meant $S_n=(\prod X_i)^{1/n}$, which gives $\ln S_n=\frac1n\sum \ln X_i$; so (c) is a direct application of CLT. Where are you stuck?

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{\alpha}{x^\alpha}$ is not a density. It should be $f(x)=\frac{\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}$

Comment: You both are right.  I mistyped; I'm sorry.  I guess I'm confused because the denominator should be $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ but I guess I'm not sure how to find the variance.

Comment: Take another look at the statement of CLT. Variance of $\ln S_n$ equals $\operatorname{Var}(\ln X_1)/n$; if you have done part (a) you should be able to answer this.

Comment: Okay that was a big help @StubbornAtom.  Thank you!